# Get a table of users by their role

Tags: wordpress, tableview, frontend, user-roles

I would like to have a table with headers in which the users are listed and also add a user specific link.

I found the code underneath which I changed a little, but I wasn't able to change it to table mode.

Also I have a problem with the link, I want the link to have the used_id behind it, but I don't know where to implement it.

```
 <?php
 $args = array(
    'role'    => 'Agente',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
 $users = get_users( $args );
 $impersonate_url   = admin_url("?impersonate=$user_id");

 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '[' . "<a href='$impersonate_url'>"  . ']</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are asking for displaying user name and link in tabular form. So I have reformatted your code to display data in table. Also `$impersonate_url` is taken inside the foreach loop.

```
$args = array(
    'role'    => 'Agente',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
);
$users = get_users( $args );
if ( ! empty( $users ) ) {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Profile</th></tr>';
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        echo '<tr>';
        $impersonate_url = admin_url( '?impersonate=' . $user->ID );
        echo '<td>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . '<a href="' . esc_url( $impersonate_url ) . '">' . 'Link</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Edit: Add table heading.

Comment: Works great!! Thanks a lot
Would it also be possible to add a header to the table? Or should I start a new topic for that?